# Linux bash: Duplicate a string for n number of times, according to a variable

Tags: bash, variables, indexing, awk, duplicates

My dataset has multiple types per name (separated by ",") and I would like to duplicate the names in a way that each line has one name and one type.

Example of the dataset:

```
Name1    type1,type3
Name2    type2
Name3    type3,type4,type5
```

My goal:

```
Name1   type1
Name1    type3
Name2    type2
Name3    type3
Name3    type4
Name3    type5
```

I tried to make a vector that counts the number of ","'s in the type column and then use that vector to duplicate the name * number of ",", but this didn't work out. My plan was to paste the two vectors together afterwards.

code:

```
VAR1=$(cat file.txt | awk '{print $2}'| awk '{print gsub(",", "")}')

while IFS= read -r line; do counter=$((counter+1)); print $1 | perl -ne 'print "$_"x${VAR1[counter]}' <  file.txt
```

I think the problem lies in the indexing of VAR1

Thanks for the help in advance, if my question wasn't clear, it is most likely due to it being my first post.

Update:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1,$i}}' Input_file
```

resulted in:

```
Name1   type1
Name1    type1 type3
Name2    type2
```

Goal:

```
Name1   type1
Name1    type3
Name2    type2
```

SOLVED!
Added a "," to the first column; If I could I would upvote your solve x100, thanks.

Comment: Are the columns separated by tabs or chains of blank chars or something else? Can any of the names or types include spaces or commas? In the sample input/output you provide it's much more useful to use values that look like your real data than to just repeat a specific string like "name" or "type" multiple times.

Comment: Your `while` is missing a `done`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Try following too once.

```
awk '{num=split($2,array,",");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){print $1,array[i]}}' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[[:space:],]+' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1,$i}}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a huge improvement!
The only small problem for now is that I get back the first type as the first name in the column (if that makes sense; I double checked and these types were separated by "," (without spaces in between)) -> see output: <br>
<br/>POLPCOGN_00341      typeI-A typeI-B<br>
<br/>POLPCOGN_00341      typeI-A typeI-C

Comment: @Daan, Not clear here, could you please update your question with same details in CODE TAGS and lemme know then.

Comment: I edited it, still figuring out how the formatting works

Comment: @Daan, Try once my EDIT too and lemme know?

Comment: I figured it out! I added a "," to the first column and it works! Thank you so much, was dealing with this the whole day

Answer (score 0):

Here is a GNU `awk` solution (standard Linux `awk`).

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN {FS="[, \t]+";}
{
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print $1 "\t" $i;
}
```

#### input.txt

```
Name1  type1,type3
Name2   type2
Name3   type3,type4,type5
```

#### running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

Or one liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[, \t]+"}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1 "\t" $i}' input.txt
```

#### output:

```
Name1   type1
Name1   type3
Name2   type2
Name3   type3
Name3   type4
Name3   type5
```

#### explanation:

```
BEGIN { # pre process
    FS = "[, \t]+"; # assign field separator "," or " " or "\t"
}
{ # for every line
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) { # starting from 2nd field to last field
        print $1 "\t" $i; # print 1st field appended with tab and current field
    }
}
```